# Update boolean based on id that matches on id from other array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How do I update the boolean property from an array of objects using the watch of Vue and Vuex? I have from_id property from the items array. If the from_id is matches with the item_id from the lists array then update the selected boolean to true.

These are my objects:

**store.js**

```
entry: {
    items: [
        {
            from_id: 5,
            to_id: 1,
            quantity: 100,
        },
        {
            from_id: 11,
            to_id: 3,
            quantity: 119,
        },
        {
            from_id: 7,
            to_id: 3,
            quantity: 59,
        },
    ]
}

lists: {
    from: [
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 5,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 6,
            selected: false,
        },
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 7,
            selected: false,
        }
    ]
}

const getters = {
  entry: (state) => state.entry,
  lists: (state) => state.lists,
};
```

**These what I've tried but it returns all the items and not updating the selected boolean to true**

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('Conversion', ['entry', 'lists']),
},

watch: {
    'lists.from': {
        deep: true,
        handler: function (items) {
            const _itemsEntry = this.entry.items;
            let result;

            _itemsEntry.map((entry) => {
                result = items.filter((item) =>
                    item.item_id === entry.from_id
                        ? { ...item, selected: true }
                        : items
                );
            });

            console.log(result);
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/b5o6gd3L/) help?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But its not working.

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] of your code, explaining in clear what is the desired result/behavior. Possibly helpful: you can [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-local-projects-via-cli) a local project in codesandbox.

Comment: Help me please guys

Comment: Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-resonance-kqzgs4